# Create an object with same key and value, without duplicating the data

Tags: javascript, object, ecmascript-6

In ES6, we can do:

```
const key = "foo"
const myObj = { key }
myObj
// => { foo: "foo" }
```

So, `{ key }` is equivalent with `{ key: key }`.

But, how can we create the same object without having the `key` variable?

I want to have something like `{ foo: "foo" }`. I tried `obj = { "foo" }`, but that throws.

What's the right way to build this object, without using a variable and without duplicating the `foo` word?

Comment: that's not possible.

Comment: You mean `const foo = "foo"; const myObj = { foo }`? Or you want it to assume?

Comment: @DarrenSweeney *without using a variable*

Comment: Are the keys and vals going to remained synced? If so, are you sure you shouldn't be using a `Set` instead?

Comment: @IonicăBizău I was clarifying - hence why I said or `you want it to assume` - you actually said without the `key` variable

Comment: What is the reason you want this? I think this is not easily possible as the curly brackets `{ .. }` are going to be interpreted as a [block statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/nl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/block)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> But, how can we create the same object without having the key variable?
>
> I want to have something like `{ foo: "foo" }`. I tried `obj = { "foo" }`, but that throws.

You can't. You'll have to specify both the name and value, if you don't already have a variable with the name you want and the value you want (as you do with the initial example in your question).

If your starting point is the string literal `"foo"`, you have to either assign it to a variable and use that (`var x = "foo"; var obj = {}; obj[x] = x;`), or write `foo` twice (`var obj = {foo: "foo"}`).

But you said you didn't want to do either of those things, so the answer is: You can't.

Answer (score 4):

If you have an array of key names, you can use Array.reduce():

```
const keyArray = ['foo', 'bar', 'other'];
const requiredObject = keyArray.reduce((obj, val) => {
  obj[val] = val;
  return obj;
}, {});
```

Comment: `requiredObject` returns `'foo'`

Comment: you should add `{}` as a 2nd argument to `.reduce()`

Comment: why dont u use it like return {...obj, [obj[val]]: val} atleast

Comment: @DenKerny I can do that even. Just looked very difficult to read to me. Solves the immutability issue too inside the function.

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is, assign using array notation, if the key is already exist, it will overwrite the value.

```
const myObj = {};

// if just you've just a string, you can use the shortcut, instead use the string on twice.
myObj['key'] = 'key'
myObj['foo'] = 'foo'

const some_var = 'some_var_value'

myObj[some_var] = some_var
```

Answer (score 0):

Like this I'd guess, by using the array access properties of javascript objects.

Any property you can access by using the string of the property name in array brackets `Obj['propertyname'] === Obj.propertyname`

```js
const key = "foo"
const other = "bar";
const myObj = { };
myObj[key]  = key;
myObj[other]  = other;
console.log(myObj);
```

or alternatively, declare the object as whole, because as you said there is no variable. So you simply define the object in code.

```js
const myObj = { 
           foo : 'foo' , 
           bar: 'bar' 
           };
console.log(myObj);
```

And this is going over the deep end.

```js
const myObj = {
   add : function(key) {
      this[key] = key;
   }
}
myObj.add('foo');
myObj.add('bar');
console.log(myObj);
```

There is no way around the not duplicating the variable name or assiging it to a variable.

Comment: *"...without using a variable..."*

Comment: @T.J.Crowder if he doesn't have the variable, what the hell does he have. Op hasn't specified what his means are to get to the string he wishes to use. Modified my answer to show direct code  instantiation.

Comment: *"if he doesn't have the variable, what the hell does he have"* Apparently, from the question, a string literal: `"foo"`.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use a creator.

```
const keyObjCreator = (key) => {
    const obj = {};
    obj[key] = key;
    return obj;
};

keyObjCreater3("foo")
// {foo: "foo"}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use tagged template literals to parse and make what you want to do...

```js
enumify = ([str]) =>
  str
    .replace(/\s/g, '')
    .match(/\{([^\}]+)\}/)[1]
    .replace(/,$/, '')
    .split(',')
    .reduce(
      (o, k) => ({ ...o, [k]: k }),
      {}
    );
  
const enumObj = enumify`{
  foo,
  bar,
}`;

const enumObj2 = enumify`{foo,bar}`;
console.log(enumObj);
console.log(enumObj2);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a tiny util (originally made popular in the react.js community) [keyMirror](https://github.com/STRML/keyMirror).

```
var keyMirror = require('keyMirror');

var myObj = keyMirror({ foo: null })
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [Proxy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy) to default a return value, that is an object with your desired key value pairs, to be destructured later.

```js
const returnPropNameAsKVPair = {
  get: (target, prop) => ({[prop]: (target[prop] ?? prop)})
}
const proxy = new Proxy({ existing:'entry' }, returnPropNameAsKVPair);
const myObj = {...proxy.existing, ...proxy.foo, ...proxy.bar, ...proxy.bing}
console.log(myObj)
```

If you want to just use the proxy directly, you can have this handler:

```js
const returnPropNameAsValue = {
  get: (target, prop) => target[prop] ?? prop
}
const myObj = new Proxy({ existing:'entry' }, returnPropNameAsValue);
console.log(myObj.existing, myObj.foo, myObj.bar, myObj.anything)
```

This should let you use the proxy *as* your 'myObj' object.