# Property 'foo' does not exist on type '{}' when using new Proxy({}), .....)

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, static-analysis

I'm not using typescript (and, right now I don't intend to) but the default set up for VSCode seems to have put some checking in for me. It's kind of handy, kind of a pain. I want to stick with it for now.

My code that causes this issue is:

```js
  let {
    localApiVersion, localDate, remoteVersion, remoteDate,
  } = new Proxy({}, { get: () => null });
```

Which I took from my [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69556012/1075247). I'm doing this because I didn't feel like doing `let localApiVersion = null` four times.

However VSCode is giving me this error:

> Property 'localApiVersion' does not exist on type '{}'.ts(2339)

The check (I think) is because my `jscongig.json` looks like this:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "module": "commonjs",
        "target": "es2019",
        "checkJs": true
    },
    "exclude": [
        "node_modules",
        "**/node_modules/*"
    ]
}
```

I know I can write `// @ts-ignore` above that line, but don't want to get into that habit.

Is there a way, *without removing the check* (or adding typescript to the project), to inform VSCode that these are ok?

Comment: Try giving `{}` a type annotation which does have a `foo` property?

Comment: It seems quite surprising you're getting a TypeScript error on JavaScript code. What is the full filename of the file you have this code in?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder 'resources.js'

Comment: @Pureferret I'm not familiar enough to help with the specifics, sorry 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what worked for me (please upvote the other answers too, they were instrumental in me getting here):

```js
  let {
    localApiVersion, localDate, remoteVersion, remoteDate,
  } = /** @type {Object.<string, (null|string)>} */ (new Proxy({}, { get: () => null }));
```

Note the `@type` annotation goes before the `new` and the whole constructor part is wrapped in parens. I'm using `(null|string)` instead of `unknown` a) because I know it will be reassigned to a string and b) so I still get *some* type checking, *even though before reassignment you can make type mistakes*. I may switch it to just `null`, and when changing type explicitly use this sort of thing: `@type {string} (localApiVersion)`.

And here is with the tool tip in VSCode:

[image: tooltip on highlighting 'localApiVersion' which reads: let localApiVersion: string]

Using [typedef](https://jsdoc.app/tags-typedef.html) will also work:

```js
  /**
   * @typedef {Object.<string, (null|string)>} InitProxy
   */

  let {
    localApiVersion, localDate, remoteVersion, remoteDate,
  } = /** @type {InitProxy} */ (new Proxy({}, { get: () => null }));
```

But this is getting into the levels of verbosity I'm trying to avoid.

Comment: `null | string` means that the value is either `null` or a string. How do you know it can be a string?

Comment: Because later on I reassign it to a string

Comment: Oh, you're the OP :) Missed that :)

Comment: If you're writing in `.js` files, and you don't have `strictNullCheck` compiler option in `jsconfig.json`, then you don't need `null | string`, since `strictNullCheck` is turned off by default, – `string` is suffice

Comment: @DimaParzhitsky good to know

Comment: It should be noted that `Object.<string, (null|string)>` is similar to `Record<string, (null|string)>`

Comment: @DimaParzhitsky I don't think JSDoc recognises `Record`?

Comment: It might or might not recognize `Record`. I've always used `Record`, but I was only ever using VSCode, so I can only say "it is similar"

Comment: I don't understand why this works and my attempt with `@typedef` and a type assertion doesn't. I can verify that the above works locally for me as well, I just don't see why mine didn't. Ah, well...

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I don't think JSDoc types 'survive' going through 'new Proxy' ?

Comment: @Pureferret - I even tried asserting the result of `new Proxy`, still didn't work. Anyway, I'm glad this is working for you. :-)

Answer (score 2):

The `{}` type comes from `T extends object` constraint in `ProxyConstructor`; in the absence of an explicit type, `T` is resolved to an empty object, or `{}`.

However, `{}` does not fit the bill, since it doesn't have any properties, while your code requires it to have `localApiVersion`, `localDate`, etc. Yes, JavaScript knows about these properties (or rather it doesn't care), but **TypeScript doesn't know about them**, and it cannot communicate with runtime code.

The solution is to type-cast at least something in this picture, so that TypeScript can infer the correct typings. In a `.ts` file it is trivial. In a `.js` file, however, this is what can be done:

```js
// @ts-check

/** @type {Record<string, unknown>} */
const target = {};

let { foo, bar, baz } = new Proxy(target, { get: () => null });
```

Comment: Is unknown a thing? I got this working based on yours and TJ's answer: `let { localApiVersion, localDate, remoteVersion, remoteDate} = /** @type {Object.<string, null>} */ (new Proxy({}, { get: () => null }));`

Comment: It seems to me that if they're going to use `Record<string, unknown>`, they may as well just turn type checking off entirely. Do you know of a way to do a JSDoc equivalent of [the TypeScript version](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgMpgK4xsg3gKGSOQBsB7BOEgQQAdgA1aAZ2DJAC5k4QBPAbkLFylEgBE4kLjwFCiUCAFsykJlFbtpfQcWQLlkCVO7b8AX3z4SEMHnwBIEVTqMWbEABpSFKkYhf9FQg1DU89JSC-D3NkAF5kEAgAd2QABSgyAA9eAApcM25mNExsL1xkAHMbLhyASjiAPgSMEhJkM1r+IA)? (I've used `any` there, but it could be `unknown`.)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder there is, we call it [typedef](https://jsdoc.app/tags-typedef.html) in JSDoc land

Comment: @Pureferret - I tried that, and didn't get it to work in any useful way. (You can use it for `Record<string, unknown>` and such, but there's no point.) Did you get it working in a useful way?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder useful *for me*. I'm adding it as a separate answer.

Comment: @Pureferret This is also a valid suggestion

Comment: @T.J.Crowder `Record<string, unknown>` is type-safe (unknowns must be cast to a type before being used), while turning off type checking is not

Comment: @DimaParzhitsky - In my view, if you have to use type assertions whenever you use the values, it's not type safe. The object has a clear structure, it should be reflected in the type -- and when you try to do that, the above fails (or at least, when *I* try it -- which is why I was hoping you had a better idea).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Your approach is to say _"Here's the result of instantiation of `Proxy`, do whatever you want with it"_. My approach is to say _"If you destructure this, you'll get a bunch of `unknown` values"_. Basically, nominal versus structural typing. I don't think there's a clear winner here, and arguing about it would be IMO unwise. One thing that I can say though is that the OP uses the `Proxy` constructor very loosely [if not unnecessarily](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69556012/4554883), and they also don't want the answer to be too verbose.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Also, the notion of "type-safe" in JavaScript world is pretty esoteric. If the value is not known in advance, casting it to `unknown` is the most type-safe option at the moment

Comment: @DimaParzhitsky - There's nothing nominal instead of structural in my approach. (I'm well aware of TypeScript's structural typing, and of how typing works in the JavaScript world.) The only reason for the named type was to make the type assertion easier to write and reuse.

Comment: I'm using nominal versus structural as a loose analogy, lol

Answer (score 1):

It seems quite surprising you're getting a TypeScript error on JavaScript code, but you can provide type information via JSDoc annotations (see [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/intro-to-js-ts.html#providing-type-hints-in-js-via-jsdoc), [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-checking-javascript-files.html), and [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/jsdoc-supported-types.html)), which are just comments so they don't require using the TypeScript compiler before running the code in a JavaScript environment.

Having said that, I just cannot get it working with JSDoc annotations. I would expect this to work, because the [third link above](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/jsdoc-supported-types.html) says you can do type assertions this way:

```
// @ts-check

/**
 * @typedef {Object} Stuff - comment here
 * @property {any} localApiVersion - comment here
 * @property {any} localDate - comment here
 * @property {any} remoteVersion - comment here
 * @property {any} remoteDate - comment here
 */

let {
    localApiVersion, localDate, remoteVersion, remoteDate,
} = new Proxy(/** @type {Stuff} */ {}, { get: () => null });;
```

But that doesn't work. :-(

Just for what it's worth, this is easy in TypeScript itself:

```typescript
interface Stuff {
    localApiVersion: any;
    localDate: any;
    remoteVersion: any;
    remoteDate: any;
}

let {
    localApiVersion, localDate, remoteVersion, remoteDate,
} = new Proxy({} as Stuff, { get: () => null });
//               ^^^^^^^^−−−−−−− type assertion
// I normally avoid type assertions, but this use of the Proxy with get
// trap is a very special case.
```

(Example on the [TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgMpgK4xsg3gKGSOQBsB7BOEgQQAdgA1aAZ2DJAC5k4QBPAbkLFylEgBE4kLjwFCiUCAFsykJlFbtpfQcWQLlkCVO7b8AX3z4SEMHnwBIEVTqMWbEABpSFKkYhf9FQg1DU89JSC-D3NkAF5kEAgAd2QABSgyAA9eAApcM25mNExsL1xkAHMbLhyASjiAPgSMEhJkM1r+IA).)

I would expect it to be possible with JSDoc annotations, since I know people use TypeScript type checking that way, but, well, I just use TypeScript and haven't been able to figure out a JSDoc equivalent.

Comment: Those are useful links! I had a quick look ([specifically this](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-checking-javascript-files.html#object-literals-are-open-ended)), and adding say `/** @type {{localApiVersion: null, localDate: null, remoteVersion: null, remoteDate: null}} */` is a) the sort of verbosity I'm trying to avoid, and b) doesn't seem to work?

Comment: for instance, it either  does nothing, or it give me this `Type '{}' is missing the following properties from type '{ localApiVersion: null; localDate: null; remoteVersion: null; remoteDate: null; }': localApiVersion, localDate, remoteVersion, remoteDate ts(2739)`

Comment: Yeah, I've been trying out how to do a type assertion via this mechanism and I haven't been able to get it to work. I can assign a type, but despite [this](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/jsdoc-supported-types.html#casts) saying you can do type assertions inline, I can't get it working. :-(

Comment: This worked to shut up the error: `let {
    localApiVersion, localDate, remoteVersion, remoteDate,
  } = /** @type {Object.<string, null>} */ (new Proxy({}, { get: () => null }));
` and VSCode tells me their null as well

Comment: @Pureferret - That will get rid of the error, but won't provide anything useful. You may as well just turn the type checking off.

Comment: Just edited my comment

Comment: @Pureferret - Just for what it's worth, this is easy in actual TypeScript; [example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgMpgK4xsg3gKGSOQBsB7BOEgQQAdgA1aAZ2DJAC5k4QBPAbkLFylEgBE4kLjwFCiUCAFsykJlFbtpfQcWQLlkCVO7b8AX3z4SEMHnwBIEVTqMWbEABpSFKkYhf9FQg1DU89JSC-D3NkAF5kEAgAd2QABSgyAA9eAApcM25mNExsL1xkAHMbLhyASjiAPgSMEhJkM1r+IA). (I've used `any` as the type of the properties; refine as desired.) I hear of a lot of people using TypeScript type checking via JSDoc annotations, but I have to say they're made of sterner stuff than I. I just use TypeScript. :-)

Comment: I appreciate the reassurance, but I'm trying to avoid the verbosity of TS, but get some of the static analysis from it too ( I know, some sort of cake eating analogy springs to mind )

Comment: @Pureferret - It does, but hey, why not? People **do** do it. Separately, though,  seems to me JSDoc type comments are much more verbose than TypeScript itself. ;-)